# Using character for sentinel but receiving pointer error

Tags: c, sentinel

I'm trying to program a loop that counts characters until it receives a certain sentinel value. The sentinel value is supposed to be a #, but I've also tried a 0 and a Z and had the same response.

When it compiles, I receive "warning: comparison between pointer and integer" for lines 16 (the line that calls the sentinel.)

If I don't define the sentinel, but instead rely on logical operators in the while statement, then I receive no error, but have an endless loop.

Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{

#define SENTINEL '#'
char ch;
int chcount;

printf("Enter your text, terminate with a #:");
scanf("%s", &ch);
chcount = 0;

while (ch != SENTINEL)
{
    if ((ch >= 'A') && (ch <= 'Z'))
    {
        chcount = chcount +1;
        printf("You have entered %d characters", chcount);
    }
}
return(0)
}
```

Comment: I know - I tried to post an image of the code, but apparently don't have enough posts to do so. I'll add it to the original question.

Comment: Every time an image of code is posted, somewhere a kitten dies. Just copy+paste the code into your question, select it all (the code), hit ctrl-k (cmd-k on a mac) and post. Regarding your question, I suspect `"warning: comparison between pointer and integer`" is due to a failure to dereference the pointer when comparing what it points to against a char literal (which is actually an `int`). Or you're passing a similar char literal to a function expecting a `char*`, or  `const char*`, etc... Post the code and we can know for sure.

Comment: I'm using vim (ugh) and it's difficult to copy text to the OS clipboard. Thus the image. It's up now.

Comment: With the missing semicolon added (after the `return` call), this compiles fine: https://ideone.com/plQwor. Are you sure it's the same code? You *do* need to fix the `scanf()` format string, as noted in a partial answer below.

Comment: Notice `ch` doesn't change inside the `while` loop.  You probably want to move `scanf("%c", &ch);` inside the loop.

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  there is a missing ';' at the end of the 'return' statement.  Is this the actual code you executed?  it is best to use copy/paste not re-type the code.   Strongly suggest consistently indenting the code.  Do not use tabs for indentation.  Suggest 4 spaces for each level of indentation

Answer (score 1):

With the `%s` format specifier, `scanf` expects the address of a char buffer, where the string you type will be copied.

And you gave the address `&ch` of a single char, which is obviously not enough to contain a "word" from input with its terminating null character.

Moreover, your loop reads no input from the user. Thus the endless loop.

Answer (score 0):

Some issues I found with your code:

```
scanf("%s", &ch);
```

It should be

```
scanf("%c", &ch);
```

Next, semicolon missing here: `return(0);`

However, since your aim is:

> I'm trying to program a loop that counts characters until it receives a certain sentinel value. The sentinel value is supposed to be a #

I suggest moving your `scanf()` inside while loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{

#define SENTINEL '#'
char ch='0';
int chcount;

printf("Enter your text, terminate with a #:");

chcount = 0;
int i=0;
while (ch != SENTINEL)
{ scanf("%c", &ch);
if ((ch >= 'A') && (ch <= 'Z'))
{

    chcount = chcount +1;
    printf("You have entered %d characters", chcount);
    i++;
}
}
return(0);
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%c", ch);` fixes half of the original, and breaks the other half. `scanf()` wants pointers. It should still be `&ch`.

Comment: @PaulRoub: Yeah, sorry, earlier I had changed it to string, then saw that OP edited ch to be a single char, so forgot the `&`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the way you use `scanf()`, with `%s` format specifier you are writing to a `char*`, not the `char ch` (as you've declared). In order to write to a single `char` variable, you should use a `%c` format specifier.

To fix this you should either use f.e. `getchar()` instead of `scanf()` or use `scanf()` (and change `ch` to `char*` then) but iterate over scanned string to check whether there is `#`.

I would recommend the first solution.

Answer (score 0):

The while loop never ends so I changed your while loop.

I tried to change your program to:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define SENTINEL '#'

int main()
{
    char ch;
    int chcount;

    printf("Enter your text, terminate with a #:");
    chcount = 0;

    while ((ch = getchar()) != SENTINEL)
    {
        if ((ch >= 'A') && (ch <= 'Z'))
        {
            chcount = chcount + 1;
            printf("You have entered %d characters\n", chcount);
        }
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a working version of the posted code.

It contains numerous corrections.

Corrections include consistent/usable indentation and logic corrections

Note: not all implementations have the getline() function

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{
    int sentinelFound = 0;
    #define SENTINEL '#'
    char* line = NULL;
    size_t lineLen = 0;

    printf("Enter your text, terminate with a #:");
    int chcount;
    getline(&line, &lineLen, stdin );

    size_t i;
    for( i=0; i<lineLen; i++)
    {
        if( SENTINEL == line[i] )
        {
            sentinelFound = 1;
            break;
        }

        if ((line[i] >= 'A') && (line[i] <= 'Z')) // only count capital letters
        {
            chcount = chcount +1;
        }
    }

    free( line );

    if( !sentinelFound )
        printf( "You did not enter the sentinel character!" );
    else
        printf("You have entered %d capital characters\n", chcount);

    return(0);
} // end function:  main
```